# How to list all configurations with their description?

Tags: sbt

I use sbt 0.13.5.

From the sbt console, how can one see a list of all the defined configurations in a project (e.g. `Compile`, `Test`, etc) and their description?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if there is a built-in command for that. Unless there is one, you could create a task doing just that:

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val showConfigurations = taskKey[Unit]("Shows all configurations")

lazy val inAnyProjectAndConfiguration = ScopeFilter(inAnyProject, inAnyConfiguration)

showConfigurations := {
  val configs = configuration.all(inAnyProjectAndConfiguration).value.toSet
  configs.filter(_.isPublic).foreach(c => println(s"${c.name} ${c.description}"))
}
```

You may not see descriptions for some configurations, because it's not mandatory. As a matter of fact, it seems that none of the default ones have it.

Comment: Thanks - a good part of the answer is in just knowing it's not a built in command of sbt. The code above results in _"Runtime references to undefined settings:"_ when added to my build.sbt - does this have to go into Build.scala?

Comment: @shawnuser3862921 when using sbt 0.13.5 you should be just able to copy paste my code to build.sbt and it shold work. I've just tried it.

Comment: it didn't work for me, and I had just tried it :) Still, if I aggressively interpret your original answer as "no, there is no built in command for that" then it's answers my original question.

Comment: @shawnuser3862921 could you please tell me what you mean by it didn't work? Didn't show configurations or just didn't compile? Maybe I can create a simple gist/github project just with this solution so you can test it on your machine, as it should just work.

Answer (score -2):

A simpler version that simply works:

```
// Add below snippet to your build.sbt
lazy val printConfig = taskKey[Unit]("Print config")
printConfig := {
  val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
  println(conf)
}
```

Then run `printConfig` in your sbt console.

Comment: It seems you might be confusing TypeSafe Config (for applications) in a question about SBT's Configuration scopes, typically defined or used in SBT plugins